# JOIN condition not works properly

Tags: sql, mariadb, left-join

I have mariaDB 5.5.6 and these two tables

**dialedcalls**

| dst | calldate |
| --- | --- |
| 098XXXXXXX | 2021-07-05 09:11:58 |
| 098KKKKKKK | 2021-07-05 11:32:46 |
| 099RRRRRRR | 2021-07-05 11:41:56 |

**missedcalls**

| src | calldate |
| --- | --- |
| 99FFFFFFF | 2021-07-05 12:37:56 |
| 99TTTTTTT | 2021-07-05 16:51:09 |
| 99XXXXXXX | 2021-07-05 09:09:00 |

I want to get JOIN of this tables by dst = to src condition by request

```
select
    *
from
    missedcalls
    left join dialedcalls on
        missedcalls.src like concat('%',dialedcalls.dst);
```

But it works on one rows and don't work on other. How i do fix this?

I want to get table like

| src | calldate | dst | calldate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 99XXXXXXX | 2021-07-05 09:09:00 | 099XXXXXXX | 2021-07-05 09:11:58 |
| 99TTTTTTT | 2021-07-05 16:51:09 | null | null |
| 99FFFFFFF | 2021-07-05 12:37:56 | null | null |

Thanks for advice.

Comment: [Edit] the question and add the desired result as table as well as comprehensive description of the logic behind it.

Comment: Using `LIKE` for a suffix-search is going to be very slow. Consider precomputing the values in a reversed-column beforehand - or normalizing your data to store only E.164 numbers instead (which is a better idea)

Comment: actual difference in call numbers in zero that leading string name. I thought that this will be catched by '%' concat statement. But it not work in all cases. I can't detect why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you just want to swap the operands.

```
SELECT *
       FROM missedcalls m
            LEFT JOIN dialedcalls d
                      ON d.dst LIKE concat('%', m.src);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=894a2c4f83ac34e59379ff6e5146b223)

This works with the given sample data. But it might produce false positive depending on the rest of the data.

It would be much better to store your numbers in a canonical and format from the beginning so that you can use a simple equality operation.

Answer (score 0):

I think your wording should be changed to

```
dialedcalls.dst LIKE concat('%', missedcalls.src);
```